# APACHE Impala - How to get values for several days by different day start time

Tags: sql, impala

I need to get the correct AVG values for each day, but the day do not start at 00:00. The day starts at 23:00 the day before.

For example I have a table TABLE1:

```
|pick_date          |value1|
|-------------------|------|
|2023-05-24 18:00:00|2500  |
|2023-05-24 22:05:30|1000  |
|2023-05-24 23:20:25|1857  |
|2023-05-24 23:45:10|1657  |
|2023-05-25 04:18:37|576   |
|2023-05-23 14:13:12|2578  |
|2023-05-23 05:06:45|3257  |
|.....              |...   |
```

It is easy for me when I want to see the date from toady. Today starts on 2023-05-24 23:00:00.

```
SELECT avg(value1) 
FROM 
Table1 
WHERE from_timestamp(pick_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') >= concat(from_timestamp(days_add(now(), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ' ', '23:00:00')
AND from_timestamp(pick_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') <= concat(from_timestamp(now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ' ', '23:00:00');
```

With that SELECT I get all values from 2023-05-24 23:00:00 until 2023-05-25 23:00:00.

What is not clear for me is how I can get the AVG value for all the days in the table. It is easy to do it when I only need to use the day as it self but the day starts at the day before at 23:00:00.
I need something like this:

```
|pick_date |avg_value|
|----------|---------|
|2023-05-23|1430     |
|2023-05-24|590      |
|2023-05-25|1680     |
|...       |...      |
```

Can anybody help me please.
Thank you.